# How to make an element stick to an edge of another element if it's responsive

Tags: css, css-position, responsive

I'm having this specific problem right now and I don't really know how to solve this issue.

Here's a picture of what I want to happen:

[image: What I want]

And I can usually achieve that with a lot of different methods (like with a pseudo-object) or having an element inside another but I've always done it with static elements, those that I know their size won't change.

For example, let's say Element 2 size is 60px/60px in height/width and I want it to grow outside of Element 1... in that case I would write something like this:

```
.item {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/g/100/100);
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.item::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/g/60/60);
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  bottom: -60px;
  left: 50%;
}
```

And it works flawlessly but when I try to make the Element 2 responsive and the image starts to resize instead of sticking to the edge I want it starts to "shrink" from the bottom, so you see things such as this:

[image: What happens]

The image in there is 1440px in width and 40px in height and the code itself is something like this:

```
  height: 40px;
  bottom: -38px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

I use contain on the background-size so its content resizes and I assume all this is happening because I'm still using pixels for both the height and the bottom positioning and I wonder...

Is there any way to do this? Like make the height and bottom position change depending what's being shown on the screen? I tried working with percentages in there but the results weren't the best to be honest.

Thanks everyone <3

Pretty much try using pseudo elements, percentages, different type of nesting and I always end with the same issue. I also tried using cover property and while it doesn't break the code it just doesn't look as well as I'd like it to look.

Comment: From what I see, the `background-position: center;` from your after element could be the culprit. Try setting it to `background-position: top;` or if you need it centered horizontally, `background-position: top center;` and see if it fixes it

Comment: Can you provide the minimum code to reproduce your problem, it might be solvable with  a simple `top: 100%`

Comment: @Hoargarth that actually fixed the issue of the image staying on the center instead of keeping the positioning where I wanted, which is huge! The container still has the static height (which I would like to solve one day) but for what I needed this works so it shouldn't be an issue for now.

Thanks a lot!